# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a page with a fixed navigation bar at the top of the page. What I need is something like [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/#).

As we can see in above linked page, the content of the page starts after giving priority to the navbar. But in my case, the content starts right from the beginning of the page. It is like the navbar is placed on top of the other content.

[image]

You can see the JsFiddle demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Viraj_Gamage/axL5pqxu/).

In the demo page, I have not added anything new. It contains the source of the page which is linked earlier in this question.

this is my navbar and the other div which have been put inside the body section of the page.

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          .......
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              .......
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
  .....
  </div>
```

Why can't I see my page as needed. Have I missed something in my code?

Comment: There is no any problem in Html you have to jst add some css properties like `padding`,`margin`,`position`

Comment: yeah, i just realized that. I thought that it is something wrong in my navbar. In fact I have misunderstood the concept of the navbar. I thought it allocates some space for itself at the top of the body in addition to being on top of the page all the time even when scrolling take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

You can see this by inspecting the element here. It do exist in css.
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: thank you very much. I thought it is something to do with the nav bar.

Answer (score 3):

In the Bootstrap template they have this css code

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

and this code is used in **theme.css** file which is not included in your html.

You can resolve this by adding only the code above in your CSS code

or you can link to **theme.css** file in your HTML code